# Not able to figure out what is wrong with code for python

Tags: python

I am to write a code in which I have to utilize three attributes (`name`, `age`, and `rank_ID`) using 4 employee objects using the special class method `__repr__()` and defining a functioned named `is_higher_rank()` which takes the input of two employee objects. This is what I have so far.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, age, rank_ID):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.rank_ID = rank_ID


def is_higher_rank(self, Employee):
    if self.__eq__(Employee) == True:
        return "These employees are both the same rank!"
    elif self.rank_ID < Employee2.rank_ID:
        return self.name + " is senior in rank than " + Employee2.name + "!"
    else:
        return Employee2.name + " is senior in rank than " + self.name + "!"


def __eq__(self, Employee):
    return self.rank_ID == Employee.rank_ID


def __repr__(self):
    rep = ("Employee Name: " + str(self.name) + "\n" + "Age: " + str(self.age) + "\n" + "ID: "
           + str(self.rank_ID) + "\n")
    return rep


Employee1 = Employee("Michael", 45, 12345)
Employee2 = Employee("Dwight", 40, 23456)
Employee3 = Employee("Pam", 30, 34567)
Employee4 = Employee("Jim", 35, 12345)


def test_is_higher_rank():
    assert Employee1.is_higher_rank(Employee4) == 'These employees are both the same rank!', "Should be the same"
    assert Employee3.is_higher_rank(Employee2) == 'Dwight is senior in rank than Pam!', \
        "Should be the Dwight senior Pam"
    assert Employee4.is_higher_rank(Employee2) == 'Jim is senior in rank than Dwight!', \
        "Should be Jim senior Dwight"
    assert Employee4.is_higher_rank(Employee3) == 'Jim is senior in rank than Pam!', \
        "Should be Jim senior Pam"


print()
print(Employee1)
print(Employee2)
print(Employee3)
print(Employee4)
print(Employee1.is_higher_rank(Employee4))
print(Employee3.is_higher_rank(Employee2))
print(Employee4.is_higher_rank(Employee2))
print(Employee4.is_higher_rank(Employee3))
print()

test_is_higher_rank()
print("Everything Passed.")
print()
```

My issue is on the lines 57 and 37 where PyCharm is telling me the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thepe/PycharmProjects/CPE101Labs/Lab 8/employee.py", line 57, in <module>
    test_is_higher_rank()
  File "C:/Users/thepe/PycharmProjects/CPE101Labs/Lab 8/employee.py", line 37, in test_is_higher_rank
    assert Employee1.is_higher_rank(Employee4) == 'These employees are both the same rank!', "Should be the same"
AssertionError: Should be the same
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question or explained what is wrong?

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [try to figure out the problem yourself first](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and if you are still stuck then read [ask] and *ask a question*.

Comment: sorry! I prematurely sent this!

Comment: You have a typo.  In `is_higher_rank`, you have `Employee2` in three places where you should have `Employee`.  The debug output should have told you that.  BTW, you should not use parameter names that are the same as the class name.  Too confusing.  Use `employee` for the parameters.

Comment: Second BTW, you don't have to write `if self.__eq__...`.  You can write the simpler and more clear `if self == Employee:`.

Comment: @TimRoberts if fixing the typos solves the problem, then that is a reason to close the question, rather than answering it. See "community-specific reason" -> "not reproducible or caused by a typo". Questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to be useful for future visitors. An oversight of this sort, where someone simply used the wrong variable name, realistically cannot be.

Comment: I know that.  If I could put formatted code in a comment, I would have done it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your issues in the `is_higher_rank` function:

```
    def is_higher_rank(self, employee):
        if self == employee:
            return "These employees are both the same rank!"
        elif self.rank_ID < employee.rank_ID:
            return self.name + " is senior in rank than " + employee.name + "!"
        else:
            return employee.name + " is senior in rank than " + self.name + "!"
```

As a design consideration, I do not consider it good practice to have a function return a long string like that.  You should have the function return a simple indicator (like -1, 0, 1), and let the caller decide what to do with that information.

Comment: so close yet so far. Its now telling me that there's an attribute error in line 48

"AttributeError: 'employee' object has no attribute 'is_higher_rank' "

Line 48: print(Employee1.is_higher_rank(Employee4))

Comment: I didn't tell you to change the class name.  All you had to change was the one function in my answer.  You've messed it up somehow.  You'll need to post what you have now.